# CMake internal error (TEST_BIG_ENDIAN)

Tags: windows, cmake, itk

I am using CMake on Windows 7, 64 bit (although I'm compiling in 32 bit).

I am trying to install [vxl](http://vxl.sourceforge.net/) library and when I run CMake (from interface) I get the following error:

```
The C compiler identification is unknown
The CXX compiler identification is unknown
Check if the system is big endian
Searching 16 bit integer
CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake 2.8/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/TestBigEndian.cmake:44 (message):
  no suitable type found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  config/cmake/config/CMakeLists.txt:287 (TEST_BIG_ENDIAN)


Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I use the default compiler of VS 2008 for 32 bit. It looks like an internal CMake error and I couldn't find anything helpful on the internet. The thing is that I get the same error when I try to reconfigure the -already installed- [ITK](http://www.itk.org/) library.

**NOTE:** When I first try to configure CMake I get bazillions of errors of the type:

```
CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
```

They don't appear again after the CMakeCache is created and I set the cmake variables. In the second "Configure" try only the first error appears.

I really don't have any idea on how to continue, can anyone help?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try running CMake-gui from a Visual Studio command prompt so you get the compiler environment variables properly set.

Comment: For some reason your cmake fails to find the compiler. There should be something like "The C compiler identification is MSVC 15.0.30729.1" at the beginning of cmake output in case of correct work.

Comment: I run cmake-gui from VS command prompt and it didn't work. I also tried to give the path of the compiler `CMAKE_C_COMPILER = C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/bin/cl.exe` and `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER = C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/bin/cl.exe` and still the same error, although it said that it found a working compiler. 

Actually now, even if I erase the paths and still use the default compiler, it doesn't print "compiler identification is unknown" anymore...

Comment: similar issue, ubuntu raspberry pi, compiling pc-ble-driver, didn't have ninja installed but was asking to use it, then specified arch and broke my config, the rm -rf build/ solved it.

Answer (score 8):

Just had this issue. My previous build had errored because of a gcc issue.

After fixing the build, I ran cmake without wiping the build folder clean and received this error.

A simple `rm -rf *` (make sure you're in the right directory when you use this!) deleted the undesired files/folders (CMakeFiles, CMakeCache.txt, etc).

Running cmake again gave me a successful build. So yeah, just make sure your directory is clean before running cmake and you should be fine.

Comment: deleting the CMakeFiles directory in the project root fixed this for me on Windows

Answer (score 1):

Running cmake-gui as admin solved my similar issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot test it anymore, because it's been long since I've left this project. It can be useful suggestion for future reference if someone has similar problem.