# CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/TestBigEndian.cmake:51 (message): no suitable type found

Tags: mysql, linux, gcc, cmake

I am trying to install MySQL source code in Linux system and ended up with this error while executing `cmake ..`

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/TestBigEndian.cmake:51 (message):
  no suitable type found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  configure.cmake:400 (TEST_BIG_ENDIAN)
  CMakeLists.txt:1015 (INCLUDE)
```

I am new to this. How can I resolve this error?

Here is my config:

- CMake version - 3.5.1
- GCC version - 5.4.0
- ubuntu - 16.4.11(64 bit)

Link to my `CMakeError.log` file
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NzMRvXsJE-YMDDuW32lkdi0IvY3MfJXf

Comment: Please don't post links to log files or error files if possible. Please embed the log in the *question post*.

Comment: Can you try deleting your CMake cache, and/or removing the `CMakeFiles` folder and `CMakeCache.txt` file in your build folder. Running with a clean build directory seems to be a common fix to this issue... see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255491/cmake-internal-error-test-big-endian)